# Compare text between multiple MS Word opened documents

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, compare, instances

I'm trying to compare two texts located in different Office Word opened documents. For that I'm struggling to create a macro that could get all the running instances of Word and allow the user to choose by its filename which one to use as data source for the comparison.

I have an idea how I could compare the two texts once gotten but What I didn't figure out yet is how to get the all MS Word running instances and their détails like the filename as an example.

I would be thankful if you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word has a built-in feature for that.

> The legal blackline option compares two documents and displays only
>   what changed between them. The documents that are being compared are
>   not changed. The legal blackline comparison is displayed by default in
>   a new third document.
>   https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Compare-document-differences-using-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know about this and was going to do all those VBA Ninja things. Thank you so much @Darren Bartrup-Cook

Comment: I only learnt about it when I was asked to do the exact same thing a couple of years ago. :)